# refresh API data from a button

Tags: flutter

I´ve does a weather app, that takes the location and gives the coords to  weather API,
and return weather data from the current location of de device,

what i want is to refresh that data with a button, and refresh when i close app and open again later.

any idea to do this?...  i´ve implemented a streambuilder to get constant info about the activation state of location in mobile... nut i dont know how to rebuild all the page to execute the methods that give me the information.

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final stream = StreamController<dynamic>();

  WeatherApiService? weatherApi;
  GeolocatorService? geolocatorService;
  NewsService? newsService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    weatherApi = Provider.of<WeatherApiService>(context, listen: false);
    geolocatorService = Provider.of<GeolocatorService>(context, listen: false);
    newsService = Provider.of<NewsService>(context, listen: false);

    _loadWeatherData();
  }

  void _loadWeatherData() async {
    String coords = await geolocatorService!.getCurrentLocation();

    final hasData = await weatherApi!.getInfoWeatherLocation(coords);

    (hasData) ? true : false;

    stream.sink.add(hasData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final weatherAPI = Provider.of<WeatherApiService>(context);
    final apiResp = weatherAPI;

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream.stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularIndicator();
        } else {
          return HomeWidget(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refresh your weather data with a button or when the app is reopened, use a stateful widget and setState to rebuild the widget and update the data. can you please try below code and let me know if you face any issue.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final stream = StreamController<dynamic>();

  WeatherApiService? weatherApi;
  GeolocatorService? geolocatorService;
  NewsService? newsService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    weatherApi = Provider.of<WeatherApiService>(context, listen: false);
    geolocatorService = Provider.of<GeolocatorService>(context, listen: false);
    newsService = Provider.of<NewsService>(context, listen: false);

    _loadWeatherData();
  }

  void _loadWeatherData() async {
    String coords = await geolocatorService!.getCurrentLocation();

    final hasData = await weatherApi!.getInfoWeatherLocation(coords);

    (hasData) ? true : false;

    stream.sink.add(hasData);
  }

  void _refreshWeatherData() {
    _loadWeatherData();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final weatherAPI = Provider.of<WeatherApiService>(context);
    final apiResp = weatherAPI;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Weather App'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: stream.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            return HomeWidget(
              // Passing weather data to the Home Widget
              weatherData: apiResp.data,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _refreshWeatherData,
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stream.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: @juanfgarcia if works well then please voteup my answer or make it correct answer.
Thank you.